# How can I process a keyboard event in the <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport?

Tags: angular, events, scroll, keyboard, virtual

I created a virtual scroll list with divs. Using event binding I can attach actions to click an dblclick events. I would like to bind a keyboard event like KeyPress to detect the enter key and mimic the action of a mouseclick. Whatever I try the events do not fire. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="54" id="link-viewport" 
                                *ngIf='linkType.TypeId == data.activeLinkType'
                                [style.flex-basis]='data.linkListFlex'
                                minBufferPx='1080' 
                                maxBufferPx='1350'
                                (onContentScrolled)='onLinkKeyPress()'
                                >
    <div *cdkVirtualFor="let link of ds; let index = index; templateCacheSize: 100" 
                    class="link-item" fxLayout='row' fxLayoutAlign='start center' matRipple
                    [class.tw-link-selected]='link?.LinkId==data.activeLinkId'
                    (click)='onLinkClicked(link.LinkId)'
                    (dblclick)='onLinkDblClicked(link.LinkId)'
                    (onkeypress)='onLinkKeyPress(link.LinkId)'
                    >

        <mat-checkbox class='list-left' *ngIf='showCheckBox()' color='primary' 
                        fxFlex='0 0 20px'
                        [checked]='link.Checked'
                        (change)='onCheckChange(link)'>
        </mat-checkbox>                

        <div class='tw-text-wrapper'
                fxFlex='1 0 100px'
                fxLayout='column' 
                fxLayoutAlign='center start'
                >  
            <span matLine class='tw-list-1'>{{link?.DisplayName || '-'}}</span>
            <span matLine class='tw-list-2'>{{link?.SubTitle}}</span>
        </div>                   

        <button mat-icon-button class="list-remove" *ngIf='showRemoveButton()'
            (click)="onSingleLinkRemoveClicked(link.LinkId)"
            > 
            <mat-icon class='svg-icon' svgIcon="delete"></mat-icon>
        </button>       

    </div>                
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Is your element focused when pressing enter? Try removing your click listeners temporarily, then clicking on your element and then pressing enter. Also you can use (keydown.enter) to only listen to enter key-presses.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `tabIndex="0"` to your `<div *cdkVirtualFor...` element. This will make sure you can navigate to that element using tab which in turn allows it to be usable with keydown events. You can also use the `(keydown.enter)=""` shortcut to only allow enter keypresses.

Comment: Thanx Bastien, I will give this a try.